# Make Node.js Redis client's .multi() and .batch() return errors in results for testing purposes

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I can read in the [docs](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) from Node.js Redis client:

> If your code contains an syntax error an EXECABORT error is going to be thrown and all commands are going to be aborted. That error contains a .errors property that contains the concret errors. If all commands were queued successfully and an error is thrown by redis while processing the commands that error is going to be returned in the result array! No other command is going to be aborted though than the onces failing.

How do I write a Node.js Redis client's `.multi()` and `.batch()` in order to have errors in results for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is still relevant for you but following code produces the EXECABORT error for MULTI. 
PS. I am not a nodejs developer :)

**Code**:

```
var redis = require("redis"),
client = redis.createClient();
client.sadd("bigset", "a member");
client.sadd("bigset", "another member");
set_size = 20;

while (set_size > 0) {
    client.sadd("bigset", "member " + set_size);
    set_size -= 1;
}

// multi chain with an individual callback
client.multi()
    .scard("bigset")
    .smembers("bigset")
    .set("a")
    .keys("*", function (err, replies) {
        // NOTE: code in this callback is NOT atomic
        // this only happens after the the .exec call finishes.
        client.mget(replies, redis.print);
    })
    .dbsize()
    .exec(function (err, replies) {
//        console.log("MULTI got " + replies.length + " replies");
  //      replies.forEach(function (reply, index) {
//            console.log("Reply " + index + ": " + reply.toString());
    //    });
        console.log(replies);
        console.log(err);
        client.quit();
    });
```

**Output** :

> undefined
>
> { [ReplyError: EXECABORT Transaction discarded because of previous
>   errors.]   command: 'EXEC',   code: 'EXECABORT',   errors: [ {
>   [ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command] command:
>   'SET', args: [Object], code: 'ERR', position: 2 } ] }

**Explanation** : SET command takes 2 arguments. I gave only one and print the err to console.

Detailed explanation about the topic is in [this](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/689) issue. See the last but one comment by BridgeAR.

Sample Code taken from the [nodejs git repo](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis)